# How to do validation on multiple textfields in objective c

Tags: uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I m creating an application in which I am dynamically displaying components according to web service data.When I have more than one textfields , I am not able to do the validation correctly/it is not properly executing the delegate methods.If I click on the second textfield after typing something on the first textfield, the code which I have written in textFieldDidEndEditing for validation never gets executed for textfield1.

I m using the same variable for textfields in a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<[textfields count];i++)
{
_barcodeTextfield = [UITextField alloc] init];
_barcodeTextfield.delegate = self;
[QuestionView addSubView:_barcodeTextField];
}
```

And the validation method is written in textfieldDidEndEditing method for displaying an alert if the validation fails.

like

```
 if(textField== _barcodeTextField)
{
//do the validation
}
```

but this doesn't get executed for the first textfield when I move the cursor to the second one.Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, add tags as well to UITextField.

```
for(int i=0;i<[textfields count];i++)  {
    _barcodeTextfield = [UITextField alloc] init];
    _barcodeTextfield.delegate = self;
    _barcodeTextfield.tag = i;
    [QuestionView addSubView:_barcodeTextField];
}
```

You should collect the text immediately after it is entered by setting the delegate of the text field to your view controller

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        // Store the first name in a property, or array, or something.
    } Continue the same for other textfields

    //Perform Validation
    [self performValidation];
  }
```

PerformValidation will be something like this.

```
-(void)performValidation {

if (firstProperty.length == 0) {
    //Display alert
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this complexity of adding validation to textfields I have crated a class [JSInputField](https://github.com/sspbond007/JSUIComponents/blob/master/JSKit/UIComponents/JSInputField.h) (which is subclass of UITextField). You can add any validation to the textfield with a single line of code.

```
JSInputField *inputField = [[JSInputField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:inputField];
[inputField setPlaceholder:@"Input Text"];
[inputField setRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleNotNullValue]; //This will validate field for null value. It will show error if field is empty.
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleLength(10)];  //This will validate field for string of length equal to or less than 10.


JSInputField *inputField = [[JSInputField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:inputField];
[inputField setPlaceholder:@"Input Number"];
[inputField setRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleNotNullValue]; //This will validate field for null value. It will show error if field is empty.
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleNumeric(0)];  //This will validate field for numeric values and restrict to enter value upto 0 decimal places.
```